# Can QGIS use MS SQL Server 2016

Tags: qgis, sql-server-spatial

Does anyone know if there are any issues for QGIS in accessing MS SQL Server 2016?
I am currently using 2008, but there are a number of new functions within 2016 that are attractive for the upgrade.

Comment: do you have a test environment?

Comment: Hi @Mapperz, We are in the process of preparing one. But I was keen to see if anyone has had any experience with this stack. Especially any pitfalls that could impact us.

Comment: I have the same question since I'm having issues displaying MSSQL spatial layers from QGIS 3.6.3 right now. Conneting and visualising vector data is ok but some features won't show in QGIS, while they are visible with FME Data Inspector. I can see them in the attribute table strangely. Have you found any answer to your own question @JWadsworth?

Comment: This is apparently a problem: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21630

Answer (score 1):

We setup a test environment with SQL Server 2017 and QGIS 3.4.8 and found that any issues we had with views were resolved in 2017. We found a lot of benefits with using the temporal tables feature but there are some issues with adding new features to a table with QGIS that we are still working through. It appears to be related to creating a new ID for the row, but we are working on using a stored procedure to resolve this.